# How to query in JMX the J2EEServer MBean?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jmx

How can I get the J2EEServer MBean using  JMX query ?

I've tried something like :

```
mbsc.queryMBeans(new ObjectName("*:j2eeType=J2EEServer"), null)
```

but no success ?

Have i done something wrong?

Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

This will do the magic:

```
   mbeanServerConnection.queryNames(new ObjectName("*:j2eeType=J2EEServer,*"),null )
```